# Can't run OpenGL code in Netbeans (Win and cygwin), DISPLAY not set

Tags: windows, opengl, cygwin, environment-variables, xterm

The code compiles fine but gives this error on run:
`freeglut (filename): failed to open display ''`

How do I set the display and get it to run? Also trying to open xterm gives the same error (tried this as advice found said to run in an xterm).

Comment: Firstly to open an xterm one needs to do the following:

 1. set the DISPLAY var using: `export DISPLAY =:0.0`

 2. run `startxwin.exe`, this is located in `C:\cygwin\bin` (for default install). You will now be able to run an xterm from a terminal. Note: startxwin.exe must remain running.
 
 3. In Netbeans, go to: project properties > Run > Environment > set DISPLAY to :0.0


Run will now be successful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a running X server, so that X11 based programs can display output. However if your goal is OpenGL development on Windows then you should *not* use a X server, because, unfortunately, none of the existing X servers for Windows does support modern OpenGL features in their implementation of GLX client and server components.

I strongly suggest you target native Windows GDI when compiling for windows.

Comment: this is actually better advice. thanks.